# Transclude not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive called first. Like below

```
 <div first>
        <p>aaaaaa11111</p>
</div>
```

angular js like

```
var testdirective = angular.module("testdirective",[]);

testdirective.directive('first', function()
{
    return
    {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div> This is my directive content</div>'
    }
});
```

on running the file "

aaaaaa11111

" content is not showing y.....

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong template ([api ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)).

```
template: '<div> This is my directive content <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using ng-trasclude directive into your template.
Here is update code:

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="testdirective">
    <div first>
        <p>aaaaaa11111</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var testdirective = angular.module("testdirective",[]);
testdirective.directive('first', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div> This is my directive content<span ng-transclude></span></div>'
    }
});
```

You can checkout [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/AmitThakkar01/t4kvu1p0/). Its having running demo.

For more details you can checkout blog http://codechutney.in/blog/angularjs/transclude-in-angularjs/.